# How to cut an image from text in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

Learning to use Illustrator for the first time. I would like to cut out a the lightning bolt shape from the text behind it, leaving a transparent outline of the shape. I see many tips for cropping text from images but not the opposite. I have created this effect using photoshop but I am struggling to replicate it on Illustrator. Any help here is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I see that you have the text and bolt in different layers, you can simply do the following:

- If not already, outline the text. You can select the text and press CMD+Shift+O or right click > Outline.

[image]

- Select both shapes and go to the Pathfinder (If not visible go to Window > Pathfinder) and while holding the option key, click Minus front option.

[image]

- Horray! You've just created a compound shape out of your original logo.

[image]

Comment: I got an error saying "Images, gradients, meshes, graphs, placed objects and text paths cannot be used as compound shape elements."

Comment: This usually shows when you're using a raster image. Are the shapes in your layers actual shapes or are they an image?

Comment: I read your other comment, for the bolt, you can easily redraw it using the pen tool (p) and then do the above.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the text to outline (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>), select all elements, use the Shape Builder Tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) to cut out all the elements you don't want.

This only works if all elements are shapes.

Comment: This crops all the text and not the shape on top of it

Comment: There is no text if you convert it to outlines. So everything should be good. Don't try it with text ;)

Answer (score 0):

- Select the text
- Convert the text to outlines pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> Win
- Convert it to a compound shape pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> Win
- Fill it with a color
- Select the compound shape and the shape to cut
- **Pathfinder panel** > **Minus Front**

[image]

[image]

*Tip: when clicking Minus Front hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to make a compound shape and keep both shapes.*

Comment: Is it possible that since the lightning bolt is a .png file, that is what is causing me the issue? I keep getting an error when pressing Minus Front.

Comment: Yes, Pathfinder works with shapes, not with images. You should trace the image and expand It. But this is another process and another different answer.